# Why does my UniquePtr implementation double free?

Tags: c++, memory

When I run this program I get a double free for my implementation of unique ptr. Any idea why this happens?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class UniquePtr
{
public:
        UniquePtr(T* t = nullptr) : t_(t) {}
        UniquePtr(const UniquePtr&) = delete;
        UniquePtr& operator=(const UniquePtr& oth) = delete;
        UniquePtr(UniquePtr&& oth) {
                std::swap(t_, oth.t_);
        }
        UniquePtr& operator=(UniquePtr&& oth) {
                std::swap(t_, oth.t_);
                return *this;
        };
        ~UniquePtr() {
                delete t_;
        }

private:
        T* t_;
};

struct Obj {
        Obj(int x): x_(x) { cout << "new " << x_ << endl; }
        ~Obj() { cout << "delete " << x_ << endl; }
        int x_;
};


template <class UP>
void test(UP&&) {
        {
                UP ptr(new Obj(1));
        }
        {
                UP ptr(UP(new Obj(2)));
        }
        {
                auto lambda = []() {
                        UP ptr(new Obj(3));
                        return ptr;
                };
                UP ptr2(lambda());
        }
}
int main() {
        cout << "unique_ptr" << endl;
        test(unique_ptr<Obj>());
        cout << endl;

        cout << "UniquePtr" << endl;
        test(UniquePtr<Obj>());
        cout << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

```
unique_ptr
new 1
delete 1
new 2
delete 2
new 3
delete 3

UniquePtr
new 1
delete 1
new 2
delete 2
new 3
delete 3
delete 0
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted
```

Comment: Look up "rule of five".   That rule is about addressing exactly your type of concern.   Essentially, if your class needs one of a destructor, a copy constructor, a move constructor. a copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator then it needs all of them.    When it needs one of them, the reason is that it dynamically manages a resource (as yours is) and all operations that construct, assign, or destroy a resource need to work consistently with each other.

Comment: @Peter This class has all five. The problem is that the move constructor is incorrectly implemented, not that it doesn't exist.

Comment: @NathanPierson  Yes, I know.   However, I was a little more circumspect in saying that operations of construction, assignment, or destroying objects need to work consistently with each other (which is obviously not the case if one of the constructors is implemented incorrectly or [as would show up with different test cases than the OP has used] relevant constructor and assignment operator are `delete`d).   I've a believer that people learn more effectively by starting with a hint, and doing some thinking/investigation of their own, rather than having everything provided on a plate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`t_` is uninitialised in your move constructor so the moved from pointer ends up pointing to an uninitialised pointer and has undefined behaviour (this will cause problems when the moved from object destructs and `delete`s the uninitialised pointer). You need:

```
UniquePtr(UniquePtr&& oth)
: t_(nullptr)
{
    std::swap(t_, oth.t_);
}
```

Or possibly simpler:

```
UniquePtr(UniquePtr&& oth)
: t_(std::exchange(oth.t_, nullptr)
{
}
```

Comment: @JeJo with only having two constructors both of which should be setting `t_` there doesn't seem to be any benefit to potentially initialising it twice?

Comment: @JeJo none of the constructors will actually set `t_` to `nullptr` so it doesn't seem to apply in this case?

Comment: Are you saying the undefined behavior is happening when the return of lambda2() goes out of scope? If so, why doesn't setting t_(nullptr) lead to segfault due to a nullptr dereference?

Comment: @weeb the undefined behaviour will happen whenever you invoke the move constructor. I'd assume the observed behaviour is due to stack allocated objects keeping the values from earlier objects. You don't get a null pointer dereference because you never dereference the moved from pointer

Comment: the moved from pointer goes out of scope, which will call the destructor which will call delete t_. Before your change t_ is an uninitialized value, after your change t_ should be nullptr, what's wrong with this logic? I added code in the destructor to say if (t_ == nullptr) cout << "null dereference" << endl; and i see the statement get printed out

Comment: @weeb `delete (int*)nullptr` is not a null dereference, deleting null is defined to be a no-op.

Comment: @AlanBirtles `T* t{nullptr};` will only initialize `t` when the constructor doesn't. It never causes duplicate initialization. And the optimizer should optimize the `swap` call after initialization to `t_ = oth.t_; oth.t_ = nullptr;`.